# Cross Domain access of self hosted WCF services?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf-security

I have developed a WPF application which communicates with a set of self hosted WCF services which are under same domain and I use the following setup in the config files.

```
<security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
```

I hosted the services on a server in  different domain .I can achieve the communication by setting the security mode to "None" which is not ideal.

Is there any other setting i can user for cross domain communication or i have to do with some trusted certificates ? I would be glad if some one can guide me because all the searches on google directed me to silverlight applications +Crossdomain.xml+WCF but i have't seen any combination of WPF on crossdomain environment.

Comment: Consider asking the same question on ServerFault as well, since you want the server to authenticate users in a foreign domain which is not really a programming question.

Comment: @Christoffer thank you ,will do that.

Comment: are the domains in question all subdomains of the same top-level domain? one.example.com and two.example.com?

Comment: @dthorpe they are completely different domains.

Comment: Does this post helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896471/problem-authenticating-with-wcf-service-cross-domain

Answer (score 0):

Windows credentials can not be shared between the WPF client and the WCF server when those two machines are not part of the same domain. For both transport-level and message-level security, you can use certificates to establish cross-domain trust, but yes, that requires having to sign those certificates and having the signing authority trusted on the client.

You can accomplish this with self-signed certificates when you control the WPF client machines and can install your CA certificate in the client's Trusted Root Certificate Authorities. If you can not have all WPF clients install your CA certificate, you'll have to get a commercially signed certificate.